# How to plot two variables by two subgroups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my "meantrans" variable for each quartile of each continent using barplot. Moreover, I would like a second ordinate to represent the variable "transcount", again by quartile and by continent, I would simply imagine points. All on one graph.

I did something similar but with 6 graphs (one per continent). I can't make a single graph with the continents side by side.

Data view (reproducible data below)

[image]

Figure (code below)

[image]

Here is my data:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
continent quartile meantrans transcount
Africa 1 0.0241636 13
Africa 2 0.0324484 22
Africa 3 0.0761015 57
Africa 4 0.059952 50
Asia 1 0.0250368 17 
Asia 2 0.036566 23 
Asia 3 0.0465116 30
Asia 4 0.0521173 32
Europe 1 0 0 
Europe 2 0.0220884 11 
Europe 3 0.016632 8 
Europe 4 0.049676 23
North America 1 0 0 
North America 2 0 0 
North America 3 0 0 
North America 4 0.0285714 1 
Oceania 1 0 0 
Oceania 2 0.0235294 2 
Oceania 3 0 0 
Oceania 4 0 0 
South America 1 0.026738 10 
South America 2 0.0348525 13 
South America 3 0.0649038 27 
South America 4 0.058548 25 ")
```

My code for the multiple graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = quartile, y = meantrans, fill = continent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4)) +
  labs(x = "Quartile", y = "Meantrans") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Continent") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_point(aes(y = transcount/1000), shape = 21, size = 3, fill = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent, sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Transcount"))+
  facet_wrap(~continent)
```

Just removing "facet_wrap" doesn't make the graph I'm looking for.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `position_dodge(width=.9)` along with setting the colour aesthetic to `continent` in the `geom_point()` call.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
continent quartile meantrans transcount
Africa 1 0.0241636 13
Africa 2 0.0324484 22
Africa 3 0.0761015 57
Africa 4 0.059952 50
Asia 1 0.0250368 17 
Asia 2 0.036566 23 
Asia 3 0.0465116 30
Asia 4 0.0521173 32
Europe 1 0 0 
Europe 2 0.0220884 11 
Europe 3 0.016632 8 
Europe 4 0.049676 23
North_America 1 0 0 
North_America 2 0 0 
North_America 3 0 0 
North_America 4 0.0285714 1 
Oceania 1 0 0 
Oceania 2 0.0235294 2 
Oceania 3 0 0 
Oceania 4 0 0 
South_America 1 0.026738 10 
South_America 2 0.0348525 13 
South_America 3 0.0649038 27 
South_America 4 0.058548 25 ")
```

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = quartile, y = meantrans, fill = continent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "Quartile", y = "Meantrans") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Continent") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_point(aes(y = transcount/1000, colour=continent), shape = 21, size = 3, fill = "white", position=position_dodge(width=.9), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent, sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Transcount"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>